# Add other fields when creating user in Django using mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I am using `MongoEngine` to store all my user data on Django.

I'd like to add other fields such as `user_id` into user data when creating user.

I already tried 2 ways to do that, but both return the same error: `Cannot resolve field 'user_id'`

Method 1:

```
from mongoengine.django.auth import User
User.create_user(email=email, username=username, password=password)
User.objects(email=email.update(set__user_id=user_id, upsert=True)
```

Method 2:

```
from mongoengine.django.auth import User
user = User.create_user(email=email, username=username, password=password)
user.user_id = user_id
user.save()
```

It's seems that `create_user` only accepts the some specific fields such as email, username and password.

How can I add other self-defined fields into the User db using mongoengine?

Thanks for your answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom User class:

```
import mongoengine
from mongoengine.django.auth import User


class CustomUser(User):

    user_id = mongoengine.StringField()   # or another field
```

You have to tell Mongoengine to use your custom class, so in `settings.py` add:

```
MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT = 'path.to.your.module.CustomUser'
```

More informations [here](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/0.9/docs/django.rst) (this is for Mongoengine 0.9 or lesser, because support for Django has been removed after this version.)

Comment: It can be wherever you want, but it's best to put it in `models.py` yes.

Comment: Thank you very much, what if I am using Django 1.4? is there any way that I can define a custom User Model before 1.5?

Comment: I'm afraid not, since custom users have been introduced in Django 1.5. You should consider upgrading your version of Django if possible.